# How to read changing price & profit % from https://www.google.com/finance/quote/AAPL:NASDAQ using puppeteer

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, puppeteer

I want to capture this information.
[image]

I tried to copy the JSPath from the chrome dev tools inspect option, and this is what I got.

`document.querySelector("#yDmH0d > c-wiz > div > div.e1AOyf > div > main > div.Gfxi4 > div.yWOrNb > div.VfPpkd-WsjYwc.VfPpkd-WsjYwc-OWXEXe-INsAgc.KC1dQ.Usd1Ac.AaN0Dd.QZMA8b > c-wiz > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.rPF6Lc > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > span > div > div")`

I am using `puppeteer` npm module, and this is the snippet

```
const jsPath = `#yDmH0d > c-wiz > div > div.e1AOyf > div > main > div.Gfxi4 > div.yWOrNb > div.VfPpkd-WsjYwc.VfPpkd-WsjYwc-OWXEXe-INsAgc.KC1dQ.Usd1Ac.AaN0Dd.QZMA8b > c-wiz > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.rPF6Lc > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > span > div > div`;

            await page.waitForSelector(jsPath, { timeout: 3000 });
            const sectionElements = await page.$$(jsPath);
```

The program goes into an error state right after the `await page.waitForSelector` line, and I am unable to figure out why it's happening. Can anyone let me know what the best way to read info off of google pages through node.js is?

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const getStockLastPrice= async (symbol) => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ["--no-sandbox"]});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
    await page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36");

    const symbolPrefix = ["",":NASDAQ"];
    symbol = symbol.toUpperCase();
    let fetchError = null;

    for (let prefix of symbolPrefix) {

        try {
            const page_url = 'https://www.google.com/finance/quote/' + symbol+prefix;
            const rsp = await page.goto(page_url);
            await navigationPromise;

            if (rsp.status() !== 200) {
                continue;
            }
            const lastPrice = "div#yDmH0d > c-wiz > div > div.e1AOyf > div > main > div.Gfxi4 > div.yWOrNb > div.VfPpkd-WsjYwc.VfPpkd-WsjYwc-OWXEXe-INsAgc.KC1dQ.Usd1Ac.AaN0Dd.QZMA8b > c-wiz > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.rPF6Lc > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > span > div > div";
            
            await page.waitForSelector(lastPrice, { timeout: 5000 }); // throwing error here
            const sectionElements = await page.$$(lastPrice);

            console.log(await parseTextContent(sectionElements), sectionElements);

            browser.close();
            return "TEST_DUMMY";
        }
        catch (err) {
            fetchError = err;
        }
    }
    browser.close();
    throw new Error(`unable to fetch data for ${symbol}`, fetchError);
};
```

and the error that I get is (Note: I am trying to rewrite the module, so you might not find the code in the published npm module as of now)

```
at Object.getStockLastPrice (/Users/X/Documents/form/backend/node_modules/google-stock-realtime/index.js:155:11)
    at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:58:5)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:494:9)
```

Comment: What's the "error state" exactly? Can you share a runnable [mcve]? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NVM!

I was able to handle them by getting hold of above div as shown below.

```
const handles = await page.$$('.rPF6Lc');
            for (const element of handles) {
                const realtimePrice = await page.evaluate(el => el.querySelector("div > div:nth-child(2) > div").textContent, element);
                stockData.realtimePrice = realtimePrice;

                const profitLossPercentage = await page.evaluate(el => el.querySelector("div > div:nth-child(2) > div > span > div").textContent, element);
                stockData.profitLossPercentage = profitLossPercentage;

                const profitLossToday = await page.evaluate(el => el.querySelector("div > div:nth-child(2) > div > span:nth-child(2)").textContent, element);
                stockData.profitLossToday = profitLossToday;
            }
```